# All files in a directory that do not end in a specific string?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I want to find all text files in a directory that **do not** end with the string:

```
hello world
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You mean the last line do not contain `hello world` at the end or the last line is not `hello world`

Comment: @cuonglm The last line is not `hello world` (or maybe `hello world\n`, depending on how it matches)

Comment: OP - you should add that to your post (ideally, along with an example).

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
for f in *; do
  if [ -f "$f" ] && [ "$(tail -n1 -- "$f")" != "hello world" ]; then
      printf '%s\n' "$f"
  fi
done
```

Comment: I believe this will also print the names of any regular files that don't have the "readable" bit set.  Otherwise excellent solution.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Give this tested version a try:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  last=FILENAME;
}
{
  if (last != FILENAME) {
    if (line !~ /^hello world$/ && line != "hello world") {
      print last;
    }
    last=FILENAME;
  }
  line=$0;
}
END {
  if (line !~ /^hello world$/ && line != "hello world") {
      print FILENAME;
  }
}
```

The test:

```
$ chmod +x script.awk
$ ls
script.awk  test1.txt  test2.txt  test3.txt

$ ./script.awk $(find . -type f -exec file {} + | fgrep text | cut -d: -f1)

./script.awk
./test1.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

```
cd /my/directory/path
for file in *
do
 grep -v '^$' < "${file}" | tail -1 | grep "hello world" > /dev/null; result=${?}
 if [ "${result}" -ne 0 ]
 then
   echo "${file}" 
 fi
done
```

The `grep -v '^$' < "${file}"` part eliminates empty lines that might be added to the end. If this is not desired, you can omit that part and start that line as `tail -1 < "${file}"`

Comment: This fails if file contains any character in `IFS`, and also break with file start with dash. At least, you want to double quotes your variables.

Comment: Since you like braces so much, I actually added the one you were missing, rather than deleting the unmatched one (or the ones you don’t need).  I added the missing quotes (you don’t ***need*** to quote `^$`, but always quoting regexs is another good habit to get into) and fixed some of the other problems.